# Numeric field overflow error when trying to seed data to Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, backend, knex.js, seed

I'm trying to seed my backend with Postgres. However, I keep getting a numeric field overflow error that I can't seem to resolve. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this problem?

The relevant code in my migration file for the table that is throwing the error looks like this:

```
tbl.decimal("price", 4, 2).notNullable();
```

The data I'm trying to seed the table with looks like this:

```
{
      item: " 5 piece lamb chops",
      price: 20.0,
      dinner_or_dessert: "dinner",
      category: "entree",
      available_today: true,
      image:
        "https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/128815256_145973603938744_5310535067466434717_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&ccb=2&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=-eruxqaC6YkAX9fG3MF&_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.xx&oh=0bf35e2fcd73032487892a2c9056e889&oe=5FED6C61",
    },
    {
      item: "side of rice",
      price: 8.0,
      dinner_or_dessert: "dinner",
      category: "side",
      available_today: true,
      image:
        "https://www.acouplecooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Shrimp-Fried-Rice-005.jpg",
    },
    {
      item: "side of noodles",
      price: 8.0,
      dinner_or_dessert: "dinner",
      category: "side",
      available_today: true,
      image:
        "https://www.simplyhappyfoodie.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/instant-pot-garlic-noodles-featured.jpg",
    },
```

Here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: `select 245.20::numeric(4,2);ERROR:  numeric field overflow`. Somewhere in your data is  a `price` with an integer portion > 2 digits. The `numeric(4,2)`  basically means  you have four digits to work with and two of them are to the right of the decimal point, which leaves you just two to left of decimal point. Increase to numeric(5,2) ` select 245.2::numeric(5,2);  245.20` or however large to cover the prices. For more info see [Numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

Comment: The most expensive item I have is $25 so I don't think this is it. But I will try this just to see.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yeah so I tried that and it didn't work. I changed to .decimal(5,2) but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm going to bet that somewhere you have a rogue number in your data. Easiest way  to find it is to use an unconstrained numeric e.g. `numeric` for the field, do the import , then do a descending sort on `price` to find the largest numbers.